# Python Behave tests not running on bitBucket CI

Tags: python, cucumber, bitbucket, bdd, python-behave

We have a Simple Python Behave based test suite.
It runs fine on local environment.

Command used to run test:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt    
behave -D URL=https://api.ourUrl.org/test/shopping
```

There's an optional npm based Allure report generation step, but that's not point of focus for the issue.

Error trace from Bitbucket run:

> `Then the shopping service will return HTTP 200 OK status                                                                                                                                                                                                              # features/steps/shopping_api.py:34
>         Traceback (most recent call last):
>           File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/behave/model.py", line 1329, in run
>             match.run(runner.context)
>           File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/behave/matchers.py", line 98, in run
>             self.func(context, *args, **kwargs)
>           File "features/steps/shipping_api.py", line 78, in step_impl
>             assert context.response.status_code == int(statusCode)
>         AssertionError`

Requirement.txt:

```
astroid==2.3.3
attrs==19.3.0
behave==1.2.6
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.8
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
lxml==4.4.2
mccabe==0.6.1
parse==1.14.0
parse-type==0.5.2
Pillow==5.4.1
pylint==2.4.4
pypng==0.0.20
requests==2.22.0
six==1.14.0
tinycss2==0.6.1
transitions==0.6.9
typed-ast==1.4.0
ua-parser==0.8.0
urllib3==1.25.7
webencodings==0.5.1
wrapt==1.11.2
xmlrunner==1.7.7
regex==2020.5.7
```

I have tried switching from pip to pip3 on pipeline & also added regex==2020.5.7 but its not having any effect.
Kindly advise how to fix this? Thanks a lot

Also note that we're using "re" matchers

[image]

Comment: For the failed test case(s), can you show what that actual vs expected status codes are? Since you appear to be hitting your own URL, is it possible you can access that URL locally because your IP is whitelisted, or you are using a VPN, but the bitbucket runner isn't whitelisted, so it is hitting some sort of firewall?

Comment: Expected 200 and getting status code ->  403

Comment: That sounds like an access or connectivity issue. If you update your bitbucket script to remove the behave command, and instead simply curl that endpoint, do you still get a 403 back? Also, do all tests fail when hitting that domain?

Comment: Yes. All tests are failing. But if I do curl from bitbucket yaml file, directly to endpoint then its returning Success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It runs fine on local environment.
>
> Expected 200 and getting status code -> 403
>
> Yes. All tests are failing. But if I do curl from bitbucket yaml file, directly to endpoint then its returning Success

So, according to me:

1. There couldn't be a logic error, as it worked on localhost
2. There couldn't be a connection error, as it worked on curl from bitbucket yaml file just fine

The only possible answer to this if all you say and did is currect is that you may not have whitelisted the IP address of the Bitbucket to allow the end point

Or, if all or some things you said may be wrong, then you could have some kinda of logic error or some support error on the OS that Bitbucket CI works on(i.g. try doing to tests in a virtual machine).

Comment: How to do tests on VMs? Since I think bitbucket is all integrated environment

Comment: By that I meant, making a Linux Docker container or a Linux Virtualbox VM, and then doing all the process manually, though I would recommend you to do this when you have tried everything.